# Displaying data from database <ul> dynamic class

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am stuck on a certain code and i have no idea how to sort it out.. the thing is i have a box which contains 2  first one has  and second ul has class="list3 floatrt"> .. when i use foreach loop the data is displayed vertically, but according to the design the html has 2 ul i.e

```
<ul class="list3">
      <li>Hard Drive <strong>40 GB</strong> SATA</li>
      <li>OS <strong>Windows/Linux</strong></li>
      <li>RAM <strong>512 MB</strong> RAM</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list3 floatrt">
      <li>Hard Drive <strong>40 GB</strong> SATA</li>
      <li>OS <strong>Windows/Linux</strong></li>
      <li>RAM <strong>512 MB</strong> RAM</li>
    </ul>
```

and my code

```
<?php
            $count = 1;
             if($count <=3){
         ?>

              <ul class="list3">
              <?php

              foreach($planValues as $pl1) {

                  if($pl1['vlue']!="") {
                      ?>
                      <li><?php echo $pl1['feature'];?><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $pl1['vlue']; ?></strong></li>
                  <?php
                  }
              }?>
          </ul>
              <?php }

         elseif ($count >3) {
             ?>

             <ul class="list3 floatrt">
                 <?php

                 foreach ($planValues as $pl1) {

                     if ($pl1['vlue'] != "") {
                         ?>
                         <li><?php echo $pl1['feature']; ?><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $pl1['vlue']; ?></strong>
                         </li>
                     <?php
                     }
                 }?>
             </ul>
         <?php

         }?>
```

but i am getting the same display .. all li are displayed in one ul which has the class list3 and no other ul containing list3 floatrt is created..

Answer (score 1):

first of all you are using `<?php` way to many times.. just declare it once `<?php` and `?>` put your code between those tags.

Try:

```
<?php
    $count = 1;
    if($count <=3){
        echo "<ul class='list3'>";

        foreach($planValues as $pl1) {
          if($pl1['vlue']!="") {
             echo "<li>".$pl1['feature']."<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;".$pl1['vlue']."</strong></li>";
          }
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    }
    elseif ($count >3) {
        echo "<ul class='list3 floatrt'>";

        foreach ($planValues as $pl1) {
          if ($pl1['vlue'] != "") {
            echo "<li>".$pl1['feature']."<strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;".$pl1['vlue']."</strong></li>";
          }
        }

        echo "</ul>";
    }
?>
```

also if you declare `$count = 1;` it will never run you code inside the `elseif`, so you class `floatrt` will never be applied. Make sure your count is dynamic for example an array `count()` from the array you create from your database. otherwise your `$count` will always be 1.

Comment: In the code above it will always be 1 maybe you are working with other code?